# How do I load a blurred images for product first then make it sharp using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want my images are coming through 'blurred' on page load and only start to clear after maybe 1 or 2 seconds when they get progressively clearer until reaching the correct resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

Fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/ws53byz6/

Suppose your image is something like below

```
<img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" id="sampleImage" />
```

you should set the initial opacity value to less than 1 in our example it is 0.1

**CSS**

```
#sampleImage {
    -webkit-animation: sharp 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: sharp 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sharp {
    from {-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);}
    to {-webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  -o-filter: none;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;}
}

@keyframes sharp {
     from {-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);}
    to {-webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  -o-filter: none;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;}
}
```

no need of any javascript

let me if it is working

Comment: That is not blurring, but fading

Comment: yes that is not blurring i need like when product images loaded it shows blurred then after show properly like facebook etc...

Comment: I edited my answer.. @RockB Please check my above answer.. Let me know if it is helpful.. Check the updated fiddle also

Comment: Good try. You can make it more realistic - http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ws53byz6/1/